# Keycloak Authorization - best practice roles vs groups

Tags: security, authorization, keycloak, roles, usergroups

I have a web-application secured with Keycloak. To keep the description of the service short, we have Users and Documents as entities in the service. The users may have access to none or more documents and may edit or read the document.

Currently we have roles such as Admin, EndUser, Developer etc. We then keep a database table outside of Keycloak that maps the documents to users and what user has what access level to what document. All our end-users have the EndUser role in Keycloak. Every single time an EndUser tries to read/edit a Document, we have to make a lookup in the database table for authorization.

We would like to migrate that table to Keycloak. As I understand it I basically have two options:

- Create a lot of roles, two for each document with names such as `doc_read_[DOCUMENT-ID]` and `doc_edit_[DOCUMENT-ID]` and so on. Then assign the correct role to the correct user. The downside here is that the number of roles will grow A LOT. Also, the number of roles attached to a user will be very large.
- Create a group for each document, with the name of the document id. Have different sub-groups for read/write and then add the users in the correct groups. The downside is that the number of groups will be very large. Also, I will rely Authorization on group names, so the list of group names has to be mapped to the token.

I do not want to add a user-attribute with the document-ids to each user. With this approach I can not get an overview of a document and see what users have access to a given Document.

What is the best practice here? Are there any other solutions to solve this issue? This must be a very common setup.

Comment: So, almost 3 years later, what did you do? and how are your headaches?

Comment: We did groups. Works great using the API, but trying to handle thousands of groups using the console is a pain. We tried to keep the number of roles limited which turned out great. However we have had issues with very large tokens, so looking back at it, it probably would have been better to build it all in the business logic in each application.

Answer (score 6):

This is just my opinion.

From what I understand both solutions are suboptimal, adding a role *per* document is unnatural and too finer grain. And as you already mention this would lead to too many roles that probably you will have to add them into the token.

I would personally use Keycloak just for the authentication part and do the authorization part in the backend. I would also try to group the documents in a way  that reflect which user roles are allowed to manipulate them.

Alternatively you might try to use Keycloak's Authorization features to handle that use-case, however I have never used it, so there is not much that I can say about this option.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion what you want to achieve is something that is very tied to your business logic, I wouldn't recomend depending on keycloak to do it. Your token would constantly grow and management would be a nightmare really.

I see no problem in having a service with good cache to lookup permissions, the bulk of the data won't change much over time.